# Proccessing "JACK audio" data with C?

Tags: c, audio, jack

My question is slightly abstract but with good grounds. I have successfully ran a JACK script written in C that loops the microphone audio data to the speaker, However I would like to know how to alter the stream of audio my self during playback, perhaps one thing I'd like to try is filter the high(or low) frequencies (CUT them completely off). From my understanding audio comes through as an analog signal and converted to a digital value (within a certain range).

I'm guessing I'm forced to go about this one of two ways, I think one way is to process each value and check if it below the frequency (or above the frequency) I don't want and then alter the value to 0(or the previous value from the last loop cycle to prevent blank spots in the audio during playback). The second way i'm guessing is that JACK presents the buffer with a full array of values that are assigned by frequency spectrum. How do I go about doing this? (In the future I want to do other things with the raw data but I think this is a great start to get familiar with raw audio processing)

**Here is my simplified code:** http://pastebin.com/Hmiumqkz
You can see that I tried printing the *in* value as its supposed to be a "float" I thought I might be able to filter frequencies from there but I'm not sure as I don't get anything printed in the console when i run this code it just loops back the mic to speaker but with out any printing to the console.....

NOTES: I have already successfully compiled and tested programs that used the Gstreamer, ALSA, NAudio, irrKang, and the Phonon libraries, they don't allow me to have the cross compatibility i need between OSs and the raw audio data I require for my project, all i ask is to please think twice before lazily report for me to use "other libraries" only for the sake of it being "easier" but I have already tried them and they all fail me.

Comment: I just attempted at checking out the "Analysers" in this link: http://jackaudio.org/applications Some are expensive for the source code, others are not valid links, or broken code that doesn’t compile. Perhaps I could learn from a sound analyser that uses JACK anyone know of any valid one?

Comment: As I search more into the JACK audio API, I realise that I know that ringbuffers are the "buffer" that stores the data (which also happens to loop around and replace slices of data) I'm guessing I need to some how access JACKS ringbuffers and perhaps I can buffer the data into my program locally and "process" the slices as I see fit.
http://jackaudio.org/files/docs/html/ringbuffer_8h.html#aa21aaf8ff173ba0e89b35554f20d4ccb
Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a better list I found: http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/apps/categories/jack

I was able to find out how to create a distortion effect and they were actually going about it the same way I wanted to do it as well. Here is the link to a VALID processing Audio application for development/testing: http://www.dis-dot-dat.net/index.cgi?item=/code/arcangel/

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really asked a question that can be answered here on SO, so I'll point you to some outside resources.

Here is a tutorial for designing EQs based on the popular [RBJ filters](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt):

http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/basic-audio-eqs.html

Most of it is written in C-like psuedocode and will walk you through step-by-step.

Comment: Those who know JACK audio will read the sample code and the explanation I’ve given and should know I was having issues with finding the current frames frequency value (Which I just found out is a range from -1 to +1)

Comment: The problem is you are asking a vague question ("How do I process audio") as well as some specific questions ("why isn't this value printing"). You shouldn't expect people to address multiple questions.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the correct answer (You'll notice a printf() function in the proccess(){} call back function) the for loop prints out the the current frames in the buffer(Frequency domain but the for() loop is printing over time so its the time-domain as well -- its both frequency and time)

http://pastebin.com/axDLw7cc

Comment: There is nothing in the JACK API for frequency domain.  All you're doing is printing each sample, one line at a time.  Which is both frowned upon (you shouldn't call printf inside your audio thread) and insane.